# How to set speaker phone off when the app is killed by the "Recent App drawer"

Tags: android, android-audiomanager, ondestroy

I implemented an app which has a button speaker, which is manually set "on" by myAudioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true) and "off" vice-versa. But the bug is when you close the application while the speaker is on, it forgets the speaker was on. The next time, the speaker remains on and the call is by default in speaker mode. I don't want to set speaker off when app is in background, only when the app gets killed it has to be set off. onDestroy() works good, but it wont gets called all the time according to the lifecycle.

Comment: Maybe set speaker off in your `onPause()` or `onDestroy()` method, depends on which you prefer.

Comment: I don't want to set speaker off when app is in background, only when the app gets killed it has to be set off. onDestroy() works good, but it wont gets called all the time according to the lifecycle

Comment: Well... in that case I suggest you should use a service.

Comment: @Strider any code snippet will be apreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a service like:

```
public class FirstService extends Service {

    private AudioManager audioManager;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(false);  //Turn of speaker
    }
}
```

> public void **onDestroy ()**
>   Added in API level 1
>
> Called by the system to notify a Service that it is no longer used and is being removed. The service should clean up any resources it holds (threads, registered receivers, etc) at this point. Upon return, there will be no more calls in to this Service object and it is effectively dead. Do not call this method directly. More info [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onDestroy%28%29)

Add service to Manifest:

```
<service android:name=".FirstService" ></service>
```

And start the service in your activity's `onCreate()` method with:

```
startService(new Intent(this, FirstService.class));
```

Hope this helps you out.

Comment: I haven't tested this, I will test this later

Comment: Tested and should work ;) , else maybe look at the `onTaskRemoved` intent for service [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onTaskRemoved%28android.content.Intent%29)

Comment: what is so special about this service, its also turn off the speaker using onDestroy().

Comment: **Service** `onDestroy()` works differently, read quote from android docs

Comment: Service onDestroy() is not getting called, when the app is closed(killed). So the service is still running on background how can I stop that.

Comment: For that reason use the `onTaskRemoved`

Comment: Is there any side-effect about using onTaskRemoved ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to manage audio manager for android lifecycle's evry method.

Comment: any clue how to do that

Comment: You have to stop speaker and release objects in onDestroy().

Comment: but onDestroy() wont gets called all the time according to the lifecycle. Sometimes through onStop() the app gets closed and i don't want to set speaker off when the app is in background.

Comment: Then you have to manage it in onStop(). When your app goes in background, onPause() will call. So, You need to manage it in onStop() and onPause(). Also, have to manage in onResume() and onRestart().

Comment: @SamirBhatt `onStop()` also get's called when leaving the app. See [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onStop%28%29) link

Comment: @SamirBhatt He doesn't want his speaker to turn off when his app goes to the background, see second comment on his own post ;)

Comment: @Samir i didn't get you. I think when the app goes in background onStop() is called and onPause() when app is partially visible.

Comment: ok. got it. as i have mention in first comment, you can manage it in onDestroy().You can also manage if you want to play music through speaker or any other resources in onstart() or onRestart().